# Can the column be unique and at the same time not be unique?

Tags: mysql, sql

**[Indexes table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIRRL.png)**

| Keyname | Type | Unique | Packed | Column | Cardinality | Collation | Null | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PRIMARY | BTREE | Yes | No | ID | 7 | A | No |  |
| AD_ID | BTREE | Yes | No | AD_ID USER_ID | 1 2 | A A | No Yes |  |
| USER_ID | BTREE | No | No | USER_ID | 2 | A | Yes |  |

How can the column of `USER_ID` be unique and at the same time not be unique as you can see in the indexes table?

Comment: column user_id is not unique, but combination of ad_id+user id is unique, so the same user can be in multiple ad_id, but only once per ad_id

Comment: @IłyaBursov Should I delete the index of the USER_ID? I think it is without any benefit

Comment: why do you think that it has no benefit?

Comment: @IłyaBursov Because it has no job in the table

Comment: no indexes have job in tables, indexes have "job" in select queries

Comment: A unique constraint does have a job. In this case, it means there can only be one row with a specific pair of values in two columns. If that constraint has no purpose for your project, you can drop the unique key constraint, but we can't answer that for you. It could be exactly what's required for your project. There's no way we can know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column `USER_ID` alone is not unique, but the combination of `AD_ID` and `USER_ID` is.

Example:

| PRIMARY | USER_ID | AD_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | AD_ID1 |
| 2 | First | AD_ID2 |

Answer (score -2):

The answer is yes, it happens, it's called a database inconsistency problem or corruption. But in this case I see the user_id and AD_ID is a bit weird but that's by design.